# Switches Have Disappeared with a Xamarin Update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a little app up which was fine until a few months ago when I updated Xamarin and also all the Nuget packages in my project. Now, the Switch components are playing up.
The text which accompanies the Switch is fine and has not changed.
The graphic of the switch itself has disappeared and the "on/off" text is tiny (as big as a dot).
Can anyone explain that?

If you look at the following image, each of white text labels is meant to be next to a Switch (they are the text properties of those switches):

[image]

Where have the switches gone? How do I get them back. Well, actually, if you put some thick goggles on and look really carefully, they are actually there, just so small as to be barely perceivable.

I'd be interested to know how professional Xamarin devs deal with this kind of thing if they can't resolve it. Do they start a fresh project and copy over the code? Sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

It is Native Xamarin and the Xaml for that view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"          
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Switch
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="30dp"
      android:text="Questions Repeatable"
      android:textOff="No"
      android:textOn="Yes"
      android:id="@+id/repeatOperationConfig" />
    <Switch
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="30dp"
      android:text="Show Answer After Each Question"
      android:textOff="No"
      android:textOn="Yes"
      android:id="@+id/showAnswerConfig" />
    <Switch
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="60dp"
      android:text="Change Colour of Progress Text by Correctness"
      android:textOff="No"
      android:textOn="Yes"
      android:id="@+id/highlightCorrectConfig" />
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/goToTestButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:width="150dp"
      android:height="50dp"
      android:text="Continue to Test"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

The theme (from style.xml) is:

```
<style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/TransparentListView</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/TransparentExpandableListView</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that Forms-based? Or native Android? And can you share the XAML or AXML or code that you are using to create one of those (micro) YES/NO switches.

Comment: Certainly. Sorry. The xaml is there now and it is native Android.

Comment: What theme is applied to your app?

Comment: The out of the box theme. I'm just adding it to the question now.

Comment: I use your layout file and it works fine on my side, could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ? To make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I worked out why my switches went all screwy. My code did not change. My `app_theme` is in my `Styles.xml` file. The first line was:

```
<style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
```

As I said, this never changed. But my switches did. They disappeared!
I changed the parent to:

```
parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
```

My switches became visible again.

I have no idea why the original code used to work and then didn't!